# How to get ul id(level_1) from below snippet by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="level_1">
    <li id="one">ONE</li>
    <li id="two">TWO</li>
    <li>
        <ul id="level_2">
            <li id="aaa">AAA</li>
            <li id="bbb">BBB</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have `ul id(level_2)` in my code, based on `level_2` I need to get `level_1` using JavaScript.

Comment: You can try using eq() with parents(). eq() is zero base index so first element will have zero index and third element will have 2 index.

$(this).parents().eq(3).attr('id');

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** if you don't know the `id` name:

```
var firstLevelUL = $('#level_2').closest('ul');
```

if you know the `id` then simply use:

```
var firstLevelUL = $('#level_1');
```

Comment: Why if I tested here your code return the same Id `#Level_2`, and when go to the parent first and after uses the `.closest()` return the id correct? http://jsfiddle.net/5fGFH/

Comment: Interesting question, by the way you can use `.parents()` instead of `.closest()`: `$('#level_2').parents('ul').attr('id')`: http://jsfiddle.net/5fGFH/2/

Comment: I think that most likely because `.closest()` will take into account the current tag of matched element as well when traverse up the DOM tree so you'll get the result as `level_2` since `#level_2` is also a `ul`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using eq() with parents(). eq() is zero base index so first element will have zero index and third element will have 2 index.

$(this).parents().eq(3).attr('id');